# enter data from key board 

Tags: c

in my program i have done like this, have hard coded the values 172.28.6.87 and stored in keys.pktfltr.ip.ip_src i.e  wrote the function like this and executed and it worked also

```
inet_aton ("172.28.6.87", &(keys.pktfltr.ip.ip_src));
```

inet_aton function is

```
 int inet_aton(const char *cp, struct in_addr *inp);
```

but now the user will decide which ip address he wants and enters it but the entered ip address should be stored in keys.pktfltr.ip.ip_src. How to do this? i am stuck up on this part

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char buf[32];

if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == buf)
    inet_aton(buf, &(keys.pktfltr.ip.ip_src);
```

More error-checking (of the conversion call) should of course be added.

Comment: An IPv6 address will not necessarily fit into 31 characters. Also, you forgot a closing parenthesis in the last line.